# C++ simple inter-process notification system

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, ipc

I needed to synchronise several processes, so I developed this `ipn::Notifier` class that uses a mutex+condition variable stored in shared memory to notify all processes.

The `ControlBlock` structure is stored in shared memory and holds the sync elements as well as a counter of clients.

```cpp
#ifndef CONTROLBLOCK_H
#define CONTROLBLOCK_H

#include <cstdint>
#include <pthread.h>

namespace ipn
{

struct ControlBlock
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    uint8_t clients = 0;
};

}

#endif // CONTROLBLOCK_H
```

Next is the `Notifier` class. Processes that should be in sync should join named *regions* using the `attach` method. In order to be notified, they should setup a callback using the `setCallback` method. Here's the header:

```cpp
#ifndef IPN_NOTIFIER_H
#define IPN_NOTIFIER_H

#include "ControlBlock.h"

#include <string>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

namespace ipn {

/**
 * The Notifier class works as a inter-process notifier, allowing separate processes to be notified at the same time of
 * an event. Processes that may want to be notified should attach to a named "region" and set up a callback to be
 * notified of the event.
 */
class Notifier {

public:
    /// Default constructor does nothing
    Notifier() = default;

    /// Makes sure the process detaches from the shared resources
    ~Notifier();

    // Non-copyable
    Notifier(const Notifier &) = delete;
    Notifier & operator=(const Notifier &) = delete;

    /// Attaches to a named shared region, creating (or opening) the shared memory area and initialising the synchronization elements
    void attach(const std::string &region);

    /// Detaches from the shared region
    void detach();

    /// Sends a notification to all attached processes
    void notify();

    /// Sets the callback to be called when the process is notified
    void setCallback(const std::function<void()> &callback);

private:
    /// Waits in a separate thread for notifications
    void waitingLoop();

    /// Waits for a period of time on the condition variable. Returns true if the condition variable was signaled, false otherwise.
    bool wait();

    /// Name of the shared memory region
    std::string mRegion;

    /// Data stored in the shared memory that contains the mutex and the condition variables
    ControlBlock * mControlBlock = nullptr;

    /// Shared memory manager
    std::shared_ptr<boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory> mShared;

    /// Flag that indicates whether we're attached to a shared memory segment
    std::atomic_bool mAttached = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);

    /// Thread that waits for the notifications
    std::thread mThread;

    /// Pointer to the function that should be called when a notification arrives
    std::function<void()> mCallback;
};

}

#endif //IPN_NOTIFIER_H
```

And here's the definition:

```cpp
#include "Notifier.h"

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace bi = boost::interprocess;

void ipn::Notifier::attach(const std::string & region)
{
    if (mAttached)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Already attached");
    }

    mRegion = region;

    // Create the shared memory segment
    mShared.reset(new bi::managed_shared_memory { bi::open_or_create, region.c_str(), 4096 });

    // Get the stored control block
    mControlBlock = mShared->find_or_construct<ControlBlock>(std::string("control_" + region).c_str())();

    // The first client should initialise the mutex and condition varaibles
    if (mControlBlock->clients == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Initialising elements in shared memory" << std::endl;

        /* set mControlBlock->mutex shared between processes */
        pthread_mutexattr_t mattr;
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&mattr);
        pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&mControlBlock->mutex, &mattr) != 0)
        {
            perror("Mutex init failed");
            throw std::runtime_error("Mutex init failed");
        }
        pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mattr);

        /* set condition shared between processes */
        pthread_condattr_t cattr;
        pthread_condattr_init(&cattr);
        pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        if (pthread_cond_init(&mControlBlock->cond, &cattr) != 0)
        {
            perror("Condvar init failed");
            throw std::runtime_error("Condvar init failed");
        }
        pthread_condattr_destroy(&cattr);
    }

    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Elements already initialised" << std::endl;
    }

    mControlBlock->clients++;
    mAttached = true;

    mThread = std::thread(std::bind(&Notifier::waitingLoop, this));
}

void ipn::Notifier::waitingLoop()
{
    while (mAttached)
    {
        std::cerr << "Attached, locking mutex..." << std::endl;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mControlBlock->mutex);

        std::cerr << "Locked mutex, starting to wait..." << std::endl;

        while (mAttached)
        {
            if (wait())
            {
                std::cerr << "Breaking..." << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mControlBlock->mutex);

        // If still attached after breaking previous loop then there was a proper signal and not a detach
        if (mAttached)
        {
            std::cerr << "Signaled!" << std::endl;

            if (mCallback)
                mCallback();
        }

        // Trigger callback if defined
    }
}

void ipn::Notifier::notify()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mControlBlock->mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&mControlBlock->cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mControlBlock->mutex);
}

void ipn::Notifier::detach()
{
    if (!mAttached)
        return;

    std::cerr << "Setting flag..." << std::endl;
    mAttached = false;

    std::cerr << "Flag set, joining thread..." << std::endl;
    mThread.join();

    std::cerr << "Thread joined" << std::endl;

    mControlBlock->clients--;

    if (mControlBlock->clients == 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mControlBlock->mutex);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mControlBlock->mutex);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&mControlBlock->cond);

        bi::shared_memory_object::remove(mRegion.c_str());
    }
}

bool ipn::Notifier::wait()
{
    timespec time;
    timespec_get(&time, TIME_UTC);

    // Wait 50ms
    time.tv_nsec += 50000000;
    time.tv_sec += time.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
    time.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;

    int n = pthread_cond_timedwait(&mControlBlock->cond, &mControlBlock->mutex, &time);

    if (n == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Notified" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (n == ETIMEDOUT)
        {
            std::cerr << "Timed out" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        else if (n == EINVAL)
        {
            std::cerr << "Invalid value specified";
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Other error" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

ipn::Notifier::~Notifier()
{
    detach();
}
void ipn::Notifier::setCallback(const std::function<void()> & callback)
{
    mCallback = callback;
}
```

Here's a test program, that you can run many times. If you press "n" in any of the processes, every other process should run the callback and print a message.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "Notifier.h"

int main()
{
    ipn::Notifier notifier;

    notifier.attach("Region");
    notifier.setCallback([](){ std::cout << "I'M THE CALLBACK" << std::endl; });

    std::string option;

    std::cout << "Waiting for option..." << std::endl;
    while(std::cin >> option)
    {
        std::cout << "Chosen option: " << option << std::endl;

        if (option == "n")
        {
            notifier.notify();
        }

        else if (option == "x")
        {
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "Waiting for option..." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Dettaching..." << std::endl;
    notifier.detach();

    return 0;
}
```

I first designed this using boost's `named_tuple` and `named_condition`, which worked great in Debian 7.x, but my target environment uses Rhel 7.3 and Boost 1.53 and somehow it didn't work there, so I had to stick to standard mutex and condition variables in shared memory.

I'd really appreciate if you could comment on:

- Caveats and race conditions I may not be aware of.
- General coding style.
- Logging strategies: currently I'm using lousy `std::cerr` during development but I'd rather use something else (or nothing at all).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What version of the C++ standard are you aiming for? From what I can see it should be at least C++11. Please add the according tag on top of the current ones.

Comment: Do you have any sample/test program that exercises this library?  If so, that would be useful for reviewers.

Comment: @AlexV I'm aiming at C++11, I've added the tag. Toby I've added a simple program to test the library. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have a rather long if-else ladder. I think this can be simpler written as:

```
  switch (n) {
    case 0:
      std::cerr << "Notified" << std::endl;
      return true;
    case ETIMEDOUT:
      std::cerr << "Timed out" << std::endl;
      return false;
    case EINVAL:
      std::cerr << "Invalid value specified";
      return false;
    default:
      std::cerr << "Other error" << std::endl;
      return false;
  }
```

The n==0 case (original code) is also at the different level of nesting that is confusing, even if it seems to me that the nesting does not have effect.